# selecting an item in a combo box and filling another combo box with data related to the previous option php and mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli, combobox

I want to fill another combo box with the data related to the previous selection. This is the code and when I write the query, hard coding the quiz id this works, but when I try to use the value of the assigned variable it doesn't work. Please help me.

```
<select id="category" class="form-control input-default" name="category" id="category">

<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "zoo";

$cat= $_POST['category'];

if($cat=="Kids's Quiz")
{
    $id=1;
}
if($cat=="Quiz Aves")
{
    $id=2;
}
if($cat=="Quiz Mammalia")
{
    $id=3;
}
if($cat=="Quiz Reptilia")
{
    $id=4;
}

if($cat=="Quiz Pisces")
{
    $id=5;
}

if($cat=="Funquiz")
{
    $id=6;
}

$connect=mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password) or die("Connection failed"); 
mysqli_select_db($connect,$dbname) or die("Connection failed"); 
$result=mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT question FROM questiontable WHERE quizID=$id");  
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))

    {
?>
<option value = "<?php echo $row['question'] ?>"> <?php echo $row['question'] ?> 

</option>

<?php

    }

?>

</select>


<?php

mysqli_close($connect);

?>
```

Comment: This should work. You're running this script when the user submits the form, right?

Comment: This appears to be a question about cascading combo boxes . JavaScript (jquery) is your friend.

Comment: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=vgocv5&s=8#.VKddhXvpXTc no when I select the quiz category I want the combo box below it to get populated with the questions with the quizID of the selcted Quiz dynamically. @Barmar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use the ID as the value of option.. and 'question' to option text?

First ... declares the variable $id ...
($Id = 0);

Second ... use this ...
$cat = (isset ($_POST['category']) ? $_POST['category']: 0);
before the first condition

Comment: But I'd like to know why this doesn't work with the query I've written above.